# How do I make a method available inside a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a rails beginner learning rails 4 and I'm trying to learn by doing. I'm making a simple blog that I want some simple user authentication on. I'm trying to learn here, so I don't want to implement Devise, etc. I have a header partial that takes care of my site header and I'm trying to put a link to logout that only shows if a user is logged in. I have a simple session controller that has a new action for the signup form, a create action that sets the current user after matching the email and password and sets session[:user_id] = @current_user.id, and a destroy action that nils out the session. In my application controller I have a method like this

```
def logged_in?

  !session[:user_id].nil?

end
```

In my _header.html.erb partial, I have

```
<% if logged_in? %>

  (My link)

<% end %>
```

When I load the page it tells me it can't find the "logged_in?" method. Anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods on controllers are by default not exposed to the views (which your partial is part of).

2 solutions:

1. Create your `logged_in?` method as a helper method, for example in an `AuthenticationHelper`. Doing this you cannot access it from controllers, though.
2. Expose your controller method to the view using [`helper_method`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method):

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     helper_method :logged_in?
     def logged_in?
       [...]
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
if @current_user
```